# How does one draw a MapPolyline using using the new iOS 17 MapKit APIs?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

This should be really simple, but it is not working.

The Markers are showing up, but I can't see anything for the MapPolyline.

### How do I make a MapPolyline actually show up??

Here is my sample code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct JunkMapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
       Map {
          Marker("da Spot!!", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.2926854029081, longitude: -71.0679634411345))
          Marker("da Udder Spot!!", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.4281694052464, longitude: -71.1093263739832))
          Marker("da midl Spot!!", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.3717488333676, longitude: -71.0670886507071))
          MapPolyline(coordinates: [
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.2926854029081, longitude: -71.0679634411345),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.4281694052464, longitude: -71.1093263739832),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.3717488333676, longitude: -71.0670886507071)],
                      contourStyle: MapPolyline.ContourStyle.geodesic)
          .mapOverlayLevel(level: .aboveLabels)
          .stroke(lineWidth: 130)
          .tint(.pink)
       }
    }
}

#Preview {
    JunkMapView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.stroke(.red, lineWidth: 130)` instead of `.stroke(lineWidth: 130)` it works as expected. Also 130 is a huge line width. Maybe something like 5? Unless that's what you're going for of course. :)

Comment: I was intentionally exaggerating the line width so I would know when it worked. 

Can I specify the color of each segment individually??

Comment: I think you’d have to create each segment as a separate 2-coordinate polyline and attach a different `.stroke` modifier to each.